# Third Order Linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solving this 3rd Order Linear ODE
$$x^3y'''-x^2y''-7xy'+16y=9x\ln{x},$$
which is a first for me. I have only solved higher order DE of order 4 and 2, but not 3, let alone the coefficients have $x$ in them. I also think that this case is special since the degrees are the same as the order, much like the Cauchy-Euler one.

What is the technique or approach to solving this ODE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $$y=x^k$$ in homogeneous equation you find $$y_c = C_1x^4 + C_2x^2 +C_3 x^{-2}$$

To find a particular solution you consider $$y_p=U.y_c$$ and plug in to find $U$

Comment: What do you call this method?

Comment: @PauloVictorio Variation of constant method.

Comment: I've also heard it called "variation of parameters".

Comment: @TravisWillse  Correct it is also called variation of parameters.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani Sorry, but how do you get the $k$?

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani I got it already. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For the complementary solution make the ansatz $$y=x^\lambda$$
The particular solution has the form
$$y_p=x(\log(x)+1)$$